# How do I upload mp3 blob to firebase Storage

Tags: cordova, ionic2, firebase-storage

I keep getting a 404 unknown FirebaseError everytime i try to upload a blob of audio data to firebase storage. but when 
i click the link that is generated using the .put(blob), i can see the JSON that is generated. i dont get this error rwhen uploading imagedata from camera plugin.

Error: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

{"code":"storage/unknown","message":"Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response.","serverResponse":"","name":"FirebaseError"}

Link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/copout-54f4e.appspot.com/o?name=record%2Fcopoutrecording.mp3

### --------------------------------

**System information:**

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0-201610131811
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
OS:
Node Version: v4.6.0

---

**Code:
*index.html***

```
 <ion-app></ion-app>
    <!--fire base data services-->
    <script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
 <!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase.js"></script>-->
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
     apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    storageBucket: "storage",
    messagingSenderId: "id"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

***recordpage.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';
import {FireBaseData} from './firebase.service';
import { File } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova: any;
// firebase
declare var firebase: any;

export enum AudioRecorderState {
Ready,
Recording,
Recorded,
Playing
}

@Injectable()
export class AudioRecorder {
mediaPlugin: MediaPlugin = null;
state: AudioRecorderState = AudioRecorderState.Ready;
mdeastr: string; 
fbd: any;
progress: string; 
file: any;

constructor() {
this.fbd = new FireBaseData();
}

get MediaPlugin(): MediaPlugin {
if (this.mediaPlugin == null) {
this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin("copoutrecording.mp3", null);
}

return this.mediaPlugin;
}

upload() {
var test = JSON.stringify(this.MediaPlugin);

this.file = { name: "copoutrecording.mp3" };

   File.readAsDataURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, this.file.name).then((data: any) => {
   if (data) {
   var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "audio/mp3" }); 
   this.fbd.uploadrecording(blob);
  }
});
}
```

firebase.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from 'ionic-native';

declare var firebase: any;
declare var cordova: any;

@Injectable()
export class FireBaseData {

file: any;
recordstorage: any;

constructor() {
var rec = firebase.storage();
var recref = rec.ref();
this.recordstorage = recref.child("record");
}

public uploadrecording(blob: any) {

var uploadTask = this.recordstorage.child('copoutrecording.mp3').put(blob);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function (snapshot) {

    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done' + ": " + snapshot.bytesTransferred + " / " + snapshot.totalBytes);

    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        //     alert("media uploading to firebase");
        break;
    }
  }, function (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        break;

      case 'storage/canceled':
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        //  alert("cancelled: " + error.serverResponse);
        // User canceled the upload
        break;


      case 'storage/unknown':
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        //    alert("error: " + error.message);
        //      alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
        break;
    }
  }, function () {

    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
    alert("made it to firebase" + downloadURL);
  });
}

}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense that we'd return a 404 on upload--if the file doesn't exist, we'll create it. There are several other errors we could get, and the server response should say that. Is the error posted actually what's being displayed? FWIW, your link appears to work (cURLing is valid).

Comment: That is what is confusing me. Actually i had to download and reference to firebase.js file because i kept getting a 404 there as well. would there be a connection problem when running to device?

Comment: The problem was adding <allow-navigation href="*" /> and installing cordova-plugin-whitelist. this allowed my app to access internet, and i was golden.